# modelling data from rows to columns in Angular dynamically for multiple store locations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

hello all i'm very new to angular js.i'm having the stores with different id i need to show the report by date followed by the store id.here is the json data i'm having.i went to the previous questions from stack over flow,but i didn't get the required o/p.help me

My Controller Code

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('TestCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  var items =[

              {store:'116',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "alchol", value : "-7" },
              {store:'116',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "tobacoo", value : "98" },
              {store:'116',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "beer", value : "-5" },
              {store:'116',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "candy", value : "93" },


              {store:'116',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "alchol", value : "-7" },
              {store:'116',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "tobacoo", value : "98" },
              {store:'116',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "beer", value : "-5" },
              {store:'116',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "candy", value : "93" },

              {store:'117',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "alchol", value : "2" },
              {store:'117',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "tobacoo", value : "8" },
              {store:'117',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "beer", value : "5" },
              {store:'117',date: "14/11/2015", deptnames : "candy", value : "9" },


              {store:'118',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "alchol", value : "-7" },
              {store:'118',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "tobacoo", value : "98" },
              {store:'118',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "beer", value : "-5" },
              {store:'118',date: "15/11/2015", deptnames : "candy", value : "93" },
     ]


      $scope.headCells = _.keys(_.groupBy(items, function(item){ return item.deptnames}));
      $scope.rows = _.groupBy(items, function(item){ return item.date});
      $scope.rowsstore = _.groupBy(items, function (item) { return item.store });

      $scope.sortByYearProp = function(values){
        return _.sortBy(values, function(value){
          return values.deptname;
        });
      }

}])
```

My HTML

```
 <table ng-controller="TestCtrl as test">
    <tr><th>BDate</th><th>location</th><th ng-repeat="deptnames in headCells">{{deptnames}}</th></tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="(date, value) in rows">
        <td>{{date}}</td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="(store,value) in rowsstore">{{store}} </td> 
        <td ng-repeat="obj in sortByYearProp(value)">{{obj.value}}</td>
  </tr>
    </table>



  actual op like dis
    +
    |            |          |        |         |      |       |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    +------------+----------+--------+---------+------+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
    | BDate      | location | alchol | tobacoo | beer | candy |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    | 14/11/2015 | 116      | 117    | 118     | -7   | 98    | -5 | 93 |  2 |  8 |  5 |  9 |
    | 15/11/2015 | 116      | 117    | 118     | -7   | 98    | -5 | 93 | -7 | 98 | -5 | 93 |
    +------------+----------+--------+---------+------+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

my required op is

```
+----------------------------+----------------+--------+---------+------+-------+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| BDate                      |       location | alchol | tobacoo | beer | candy |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14/11/2015                 | 116            | -7     | 98      | -5   | 93    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14/11/2015                 | 117            |  2     | 8       | 5    | 9       |      |       |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15/11/2015                 | 116            | -7     | 98      | -5   | 93    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15/11/2015                 | 118            | -7     | 98      | -5   | 93         |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for this?

Comment: Yes I can  – Shailendra Singh Deol

Comment: here is the plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/k93AHNJPjYrlAQODPP5t?p=preview